# How to change title of cmd window without get user info first?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, title

With the Windows `title` command it is possible to change title of the current cmd window, like:

```
title Alfa
```

But when logged in as "Administrator" this makes the title "Administrator: Alfa", so when the Windows taskbar is at the side of the monitor, it looks:

[image]

Thus not much relevant information.

Is there a way to change the title of a cmd Window, without getting the initial user information?

It is OK if it requires additional scripting or programming in e.g. Python or C.

Note: Jonno pointed to this ["How to remove 'Administrator:' from the command prompt title"](https://serverfault.com/questions/35561/how-to-remove-administrator-from-the-command-promt-title) question and answer at ServerFault, so looks like there may not be any easy answer.

Comment: Check [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/35561/how-to-remove-administrator-from-the-command-promt-title)

Comment: Administrator: %0 is not found in the W10 cmd.exe.mui file, so that specific hack will not work in W10.